# How can I change the color of the <div> using javascript without using onClick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the background color of the `<div>` using javascript without clicking the `<div>` itself. Basically the background color will change by itself or on load.

Here is my `HTML` Code:

```
    <div id="divChange" onclick="myDIV()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Passport <?php echo "<strong><a href=\"view_latest_passport.php?id=$id\"> $passport</a> /&nbsp; Passport Expiration Date:</strong> $passport_expiration"; ?>
    </div>
```

and here's my `javascript` code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myDIV() {
  document.getElementById("divChange").style.color="red";
}
</script>
```

Comment: *"by itself or on load"* - Call me crazy, but maybe by calling `myDIV()` from a window.onload event handler instead of from an onclick event handler? (Or just call it directly from a script element that appears after the element in question.) There are any number of questions and tutorials and so forth about how to run an arbitrary bit of JavaScript on page load...

Comment: Read about `onload` event [http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

Comment: sorry im new to javascript. i only know few in javascript. what event handler are you talking instead of onclick?

Comment: @nnnnnn – How about `CSS` ?

Comment: just call your function in body onload. e.g. <body onload="myDIV()">

Comment: You can add an onload event to your html like this: <body onload="myDIV()">

Comment: If you want to change the background color, use the *backgroundColor* property, not *color*.

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
         <div id="divChange" onclick="myDIV()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Passport <?php echo "<strong><a href=\"view_latest_passport.php?id=$id\"> $passport</a> /&nbsp; Passport Expiration Date:</strong> $passport_expiration"; ?>
    </div>
        <script>
           document.getElementById("divChange").style.backgroundColor="red";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.onload` event to trigger `myDIV` method

```js
//call your myDIV on window.onload
window.onload = function(){
     myDIV();
 }
function myDIV() {
  //this triggers only the text color
  document.getElementById("divChange").style.color="white";
  
  //use this to change background color
  document.getElementById("divChange").style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```

```html
<div id="divChange">Sample DIV</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute a JavaScript immediately after a page has been loaded, check link.

http://codepen.io/anil329/pen/kXvaPr

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body onload="myDiv()">

    <div id="divChange">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Passport 
    </div>

    <script>
    function myDiv() {
      document.getElementById("divChange").style.color="red";
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative #1 (with JQuery)

If you are using JQuery you can use [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/teocci/r5s4186n/1/).

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  var div = document.getElementById('divChange');
  div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divChange">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Passport <strong><a href="view_latest_passport.php?id=$id"> My Passport</a> /&nbsp; Passport Expiration Date:</strong> 23 JUN 2015
</div>
```

### Alternative #2 (without JQuery)

Also you can use [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/teocci/q8j0f577/)

```html
<body onload="myDiv()">
...
  <div id="divChange">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Passport <strong>
    <a href="view_latest_passport.php?id=$id"> My Passport</a> &nbsp; Passport Expiration Date:</strong> 23 JUN 2015
  </div>
 ... 
  <script>
  function myDiv() {
      var div = document.getElementById( 'divChange' );
      div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your myDIV() method onload event.

```
<body onload="myDIV()">
your content goes here.
</body>
```

Thanks.